# ¿Porque esta consulta no valida la condición formada por otro query (Subconsulta)?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy usando Oracle sql y necesito crear un query para validar los estudiantes que se registraron y no estan en una cola de inscripción, en otras palabras;

**Lo que trato de lograr:** Quiero mostrar todos los registros de la tabla "estudiantes" que no esten insertados en la tabla "cola_estudiantes".

**Los datos que tengo:** En la tabla estudiantes hay un campo llamado "fcCarnet" de tipo varchar con longuitud de 20 bytes. En la tabla cola_estudiantes tengo un campo que tambien se llama "fcCarnet" y tambien con tipo varchar de 20 bytes.

**Lo que he intentado:** cree la consulta `select * from estudiante where fcCarnet not in (select fcCarnet from cola_estudiantes)` pero esto no funcionó pues me trajo todos los registros de la tabla estudiante. Para descartar que la subconsulta no estuviese vacia trate de consultar con `select * from estudiantes where fcCarnet in (select fcCarnet from cola_estudiantes)` pero esta vez no trajo ningún registro, entonces intenté solo consultar el fcCarnet de la tabla cola_estudiantes y esta consulta si trajo resultados (`select fcCarnet from cola_estudiantes`)

Aqui dejo las imagenes de datos y consultas para mayor orientación:
[image: Este carnet "999" esta en la tabla estudiantes]
[image: El mismo carnet tambien esta en la cola estudiantes por lo que no quiero que el query traiga este registro]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu nombre `fcccarnet` está en mayúsculas en la tabla y lo buscas como minúsculas. Probablemente ese no sea el problema, porque te hubiera saltado un error en lugar de aparcar solo vacío, pero para descartar.

También podrías intentar la puta subconsulta `select fcCarnet from cola_estudiantes` y decirnos que trae?

Por último revisa que no haya espacios, ya que recuerda que `999` no es lo mismo que `999 ` un espacio lo cambia todo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por esa observación que realmente se me habia pasado. En efecto, eran los espacios. Sucedió que la tabla la poble desde un aplicativo en java web, entonces, el insert se llevaba acabo con un salto de linea (No se porque, puesto que no le he agrego ese salto para nada) pero de igual forma lo modifique manual y ahora la consulta si trae lo que necesito. Si alguien más tiene un detalle similar, en java user el metodo .trim() para eliminar espacios en blanco y saltos de linea en blanco.